Leaflet map included in an html exported from Obsidian.md only shows up after page reload / refresh
My goal:
I exported some html notes from Obsidian.md (based on this: https://github.com/KosmosisDire/obsidian-webpage-export) and am now trying to include an interactive (fictional) worldmap based on the leaflet.js script.
Not using the leaflet Plugin for Obsidian, since this didn't work for me in the export.
My problem:
When first opening the page or navigating there from another note in the hierarchy, the map image and UI are gone. Which means that I only see a completely empty frame in the size of the map. This is different from when just the image is not loaded - then the map content would be light grey.
So I'm just guessing that the script (as well as the css?) isn't loaded (including the Map UI overlay). The map only works fine after I reload the page, showing the typical leaflet zoom UI as well.
I'm testing everything locally with the help of VS Code and Five Server as local webserver. There are no errors in my code (I fixed some errors caused by the generated export from Obsidian). The same problem is visible when I upload it to my webspace or try it with different browsers.
Hoping that someone here can help me, since I'm pretty sure that others who would like to have such an interactive worldmap combined with an Obsidian based page as well might stumble on this problem as well and hopefully also find the solution for this here some day.
What i tried so far:
I looked on stackoverflow for similar questions and already tried solutions not only for leaflet but also for other problems with scripts not executing without a refresh/reload of the page. But nothing helped.
I included the script in a simpler html and played around with a link to another page and returning to the one with the map - it worked. So I guess it's a problem with something the other scripts in the document do (there is some ajax and pixy included which I can't remove since it's needed for a graphview navigation which is part of Obsidian).
I searched on stackoverflow for solutions again.
I tried using cache, defer, preload and placing the link to the script and the script (and css) itself into different places in the html file and different folders.
I tried removing other scripts in the html file to see if it helps.
But all of this didn't change the behaviour, only caused more errors and problems on the page (or with the leaflet UI).
So far, I haven't found any solution that helped me. I don't get any error message, so there is nothing I can post here unfortunately.
And yes, I am no programmer/web dev, so unfortunately I am currently not able to come up with any more elaborate solutions. I was just looking for a way to present my writing/content in a nice way.
This is the map script I'm using:
<script> 
// Using leaflet.js to pan and zoom a big image. 
           const map = L.map('image-map', {
             minZoom: 1,
             maxZoom: 4,
             center: [0, 0],
             zoom: 1,
             maxBoundsViscosity: 1,
             crs: L.CRS.Simple
           });
           var image= L.imageOverlay("I removed the name of my asset here, but using a webp which works", [[0,0],[240,330]]); //initial size at zoom 1 )
           image.addTo(map);
// tell leaflet that the map is exactly as big as the image
map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds([0,0], [240,330]));  // prevent panning outside the image area.
    //Note the viscosity setting keeps the image from being dragged outside this 
</script>


Meanwhile, I got help elsewhere and I want to share the current solution here for those who are struggling with the same problem:
I put the script inside another html file linked via iframe and included this iframe in the problematic html page exported from Obsidian instead. This way, it gets properly loaded on first load and after navigating around the page.
I am sure there must be other solutions, so feel free to contribute if you know one.
For me this works for now!
